# how to change property to used static value in class?

Tags: typescript

```js
class Parent {
    currentStatus: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
}

class Test extends Parent {
    public static status = {
        a: 'a',
    };
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.currentStatus = Test.status.a;
    }
}
```

How should I do it?

I'd like to put the value in CurrentStatus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to put the value in `CurrentStatus`.

The error is happening because we cannot assign a type of `string` to a string literal union type of `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`.

You can use [`as const`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510) to make sure that `Test.status.a` is of the string literal type `'a'`, which is inside the domain of `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`, instead of it being widened to the type `string`, which is outside of the domain.

```
class Parent {
    currentStatus: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
}

class Test extends Parent {
    public static status = {
        a: 'a' as const,
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.currentStatus = Test.status.a;
    }
}
```